# My simple PHP function for maintaining values in my form isn't working. Really newbie!

Tags: php, function

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
    function getValue($field){
        if(isset($_GET[$field])){
            return $_GET[$field];
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    ?>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="class2.php" method="get">
        <dl>
            <dt>First Name:</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(getValue($_GET['name'])) ?>" name="name" />                    
            </dd>                

            <dt>Last Name:</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(getValue($_GET['lastname'])) ?>" name="lastname" />                    
            </dd>

            <br />                
            <dt>
                <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
            </dt>                
        </dl>
    </form>
</body>
```

If I write a value in Name and nothing in LastName, the value in Name SHOULD stay there, right? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using

```
getValue($_GET['name'])
```

instead of

```
getValue( 'name' )
```

You are calling `getValue()` with the **contents** of `$_GET['name']` right now

Also:
Your `getValue` function doesn't make much sense right now. Why not build in `htmlspecialchars()` into it directly instead of applying it to its return value?

Answer (score 1):

`getValue('name')` not `getValue($_GET['name']);`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you really need a function just to retrieve an elem of the `$_GET` array?

Because you're reading a GET request, if you refresh this page and don't submit your form (and clear the query string), you'll lose your data in `$_GET`.

If you want to keep hold of this information, you can place it [in the session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) ($_SESSION).

Don't forget to [filter your input and escape your output](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=php+filter+input+escape+output).

Answer (score 0):

Within the `<dd><input...` tags, that PHP should read:

```
<dd><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(getValue( 'name' )) ?>" name="name" />
```

The function you wrote knows to take that value `name`, and look for it within the `GET` array, no need to tell it to do that when you call it.